# How to edit a playlist of a YouTube channel I manage

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-channel

I have a YouTube account which is the Manager of a YouTube channel. I created a playlist in the channel's YouTube Studio. Then, in the **Playlist details** panel, I set the **Default video order** to **Manually sorted in YouTube**. This should make it possible to reorder the playlist when viewed in YouTube using the `═` icons left to each video's thumbnail. However, I am unable to reorder the playlist.

- When viewing the playlist using my account, the option to edit and rearrange the playlist does not show.
- If I click on my profile picture, select **Switch account** and navigate to the channel's account, I get redirected to the YouTube studio.

Other editing options (such as removing videos) are also unavailable.

How can I edit the playlist of a YouTube channel?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a bug that's now (July 20, 2023) resolved. Now if I click on my profile picture in the YouTube main page and select **Switch account**, I can navigate to the channel's view of the YouTube main page. Then, I can go to the playlist and reorder it.